# calling shell command from php has different behavior than in shell

Tags: php, shell

I've written this simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
STORAGE_PATH=/tmp/;
export STORAGE_PATH;
cd STORAGE_PATH;
perl /{SOME_PATH}/perl-script.pl;
```

When I call it from shell, it works perfectly as expected. But from PHP it hangs infinitely, and when debugging, I found that it hangs during the Perl execution which doesn't really make any sense since it continues if it was called in shell.

Did I make any mistake with the shebang `#!/bin/sh`? I tried with `#!/bin/bash` too.

I tried with all variations in php: `exec`, `system`, `shell_exec`, `callthru` but nothing is working..

Did I miss something?

Comment: Does apache have permission to execute the perl script?

Comment: Aside from checking permissions try using an absolute path to the perl binary, and any others you might be calling inside your perl script. The `$PATH` environment var frequently differs between login accounts and service accounts.

Comment: You can see what the script is doing while it executes by adding *-x* to your #! line   **#!/bin/sh -x**

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't see how it worked in shell.

You are calling `/{SOME_PATH}/perl-script.pl` but the variable `SOME_PATH` is not defined. Did you mean `STORAGE_PATH`? Also, you forgot the `$` before `{`.

While you're at it, check that the user running the webserver has permissions to execute both scripts.

Comment: sorry may be I had to say it explicitly that {SOME_PATH} is a static path which I didn't write in the post only to keep it simple and clear.

Comment: I checked the permissions too, www-data (the user of the webserver) has the permissions to execut both scripts, and even tried it with (sudo su www-data) and the execution of the perl script worked fine. With the call of php something goes wrong. :-/

Comment: Turn on debug output in PHP - either to log file or to echo output and let us know what it says.

Comment: Thx guys but its the perl script which stops in at some point, and only when its called from php, I dont know what I can really show u, there r no errors no strange output.. I dont know how u can help me, i will keep u informed of this strange phonemene.

Comment: I'm getting a bit crazy, the only difference is the tty field between both calls.. from the shell it's: pts/2 and from apche it's: ? (so a deamon).. That should be ok? What the hell has the perl script with that to do? why does it hang??? not logical or?